# Somebody who attracts a lot of attention or interest

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose you are introducing some people to each other. Among these people there is a very intelligent person or a very admirable person or an old mother who has suffered a lot or even a very successful athlete who you are going to highlight him in your introduction in the manner that you could put him / her in the center of attraction or attention. What would you say in natural, colloquial sense in this case in the US?

The only thing I found from my dictionaries was only:

> - ...and finally this is Ivan; the cynosure of our company.

Does it make any sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

*Cynosure* definitely isn't a common word – I haven't heard it before, and if I came across it I would have to infer from context what it meant.

For the example with an intelligent/admirable person or a successful athlete, you could use (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**star**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/star)
>   A very famous or talented entertainer or sports player:
>   "*a sport star*"
>   [AS MODIFIER]: "*she got star treatment*"
>
> An outstandingly successful person or thing in a group:
>   "*he's a rising star in the party*"
>   [AS MODIFIER]: "*Elinor was a star pupil*"

You couldn't use this for the "mother" example, but in that case it may be appropriate to use:

> [**bastion**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bastion)
>   An institution, place, or person strongly maintaining particular principles, attitudes, or activities:
>   "*cricket’s last bastion of discrimination*"

You might call her *a bastion* if you were referring to admirable qualities, perhaps you wanted to call attention to her strong resolve, her strong will, or her [**steadfast**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/steadfast) determination to carry on.